# Deja-Dup restoral failed

Tags: 16.04, restore, deja-dup

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and I had to reinstall the entire OS because of glitches.  I tried to restore my home folder from the backup I made, but it says

```
Restore Failed.  File /duplicity-full.20170425T141908Z.vol71.difftar.gpg does not exist.
```

And then it just stops the entire restoral.  How do I fix this?

Comment: does the file exist?

Comment: @ravery Yes it does

Comment: the only thing Ican think of is that the path is incorrect. or the program doesn't have read access to the file.

Comment: @ravery I just checked.  The path is correct, and everybody on the planet has read access to the file.